# How to remove unwanted noise peaks in sound files in Windows?

Tags: audacity, audio-processing

How can I remove the peaks in the top channel shown in the image? They are noises.
This image is from audacity

[image: sample]

Comment: Which Operating System? Which software are you using?

Comment: @techie007: edited the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried Audacity's [Noise Removal feature(s)](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Noise_Removal)?

This may be more of a 'click' than a 'noise' (looks like it), so perhaps you'll have better luck with the Audacity ["Click Removal"](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Click_Removal) features?

Example of what's on the page:

> Sometimes an even better result can be obtained by zooming in (CTRL + 1) to near sample level and either silencing the click (Edit > Silence), or using the Draw Tool to smooth out the contours of the samples and so attenuate the click.

Comment: no it is not providing desired result i tried in many ways

Comment: is it possible to just cut the spikes in the top channel ?

Comment: @Siva - I added the wiki page for the Click Removal suggestions/features.

Comment: it is a huge file 10 hours, so will it be practical to use this feature first of all ?

Answer (score 4):

Truncating peaks like that can be done using the Limiter (Effect > Limiter).

You probably want to use a "Hard Limit", as only to affect the peaks. Also, you can of course use it multiple times in combination with Effect > Normalize to shrink those peaks while scaling up the remainder of the recording to cover the full volume range.

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't tried them yet, Effect > Leveller and Effect > Click Removal in Audacity might work here.

Comment: it is not working anyother options ?

Comment: is it possible to just cut the spikes in the top channel ?

Comment: Try it and find out. regards,